# T-SQL can't excute my procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My code:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
                   text VARCHAR(255)
                  );
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(@string VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test (text) VALUES (@string);
    SELECT * FROM test;
END 
GO

EXEC testProc('Test01')
```

The error I get after running it:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Test01'.*

I want to insert `'Test01'` into my table test with the help of the proc `testProc`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Remove the parenthesis around parameter `EXEC testProc 'Test01'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to omit the parentheses.

```
EXEC testProc @string  = 'Test01';
```

Comment: Thx for helping @S.Karras!